# Can I tunnel internet from one computer to another in my network?

Tags: vpn

I have a work laptop that stays connected to my company's VPN most of the day, but would like to use another machine in my household to do some work.

Is it possible to tunnel all traffic from the other machine through to the machine connected to VPN?

Unfortunately, configuring the VPN to connect to my employer's network on another personal machine is not option.

Comment: If you can configure your work laptop to forward other traffic it receives through the VPN (under Linux, this needs root rights), then yes, you can. If you don't have appropriate rights to configure it on your work laptop, then no, you can't.

Comment: Both machines are MacOS. I have admin privileges on both. The question is, how?

Comment: I need to do it as well. Will be great if you can share how you did this. With Covid-19 lock-down, and my laptop's battery that decided to give on me. I need to save battery as much as possible.
It's not even possible to get a gigabit-ethernet connector, so looking for ways to connect to VPN from another system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both machines are unix and you don't have issues with slight latency, the simplest way may be to run laptop programs by x11 forwarding.

```
ssh -Y user@laptopip
```

Then, just run firefox& or whatever other programs and you'll be working with the laptop's applications forwarded to your desktop's screen.

<s>Alternatively,</s>

```
ssh -D 1337 user@laptopip -N
```

Then set the proxy in your browser to localhost:1337.

Edit:  This second option didn't work when I just tried it; one would probably have to set some forwarding up on the laptop, if not change an sshd config item or run a proxy on the laptop.

Comment: I need more details. Both machines are MacOS. I did `ssh -Y user@work-laptop-ip` from my personal machine. I was successfully logged in but then I got my prompt back. Now what?